# What are these operators for at the top of a script?

Tags: macros, lua, preprocessor

There are two operators that I am questioning. When I put `#` or `$` at the top of a script, my script editor changes their colors to the same as the comment color and pre-processor color respectively. If they are pre-processor macros, could someone give an example use or situation when they'd be used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29), a Unix script file convention.